# rails 4 complex model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, getter-setter

I have a rails app. Assigner(current_user) must assign a task to executor(other user). I'm using getter setter method for jquery autocomplete and with the validation so I can make sure if there is an existing user who the task is assigned to. I'm using the rescue set to nil so either if the field empty or the user is non-existing can be validated with presence of. I'd like to change this, so users either could leave the field empty or choosing from existing users. As I'm validating the executor object I'm not sure how I can do that.

task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"

  validates :assigner, presence: true
  validates :executor, presence: { message: "must be valid"}

  def task_name_company
    [executor.try(:profile).try(:first_name),      executor.try(:profile).try(:last_name), executor.try(:profile).try(:company)].join(' ')
  end

  def task_name_company=(name)
    self.executor = User.joins(:profile).where("CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name, company) LIKE ?", "%#{name}%").first if name.present?
  rescue ArgumentError
    self.executor = nil
  end
```